Send data to different component with angular emit
There is a button that calculates desi on the product editing page. When this button is clicked, a different component, the modal, opens. In the opened modal, desi calculation is made by taking the necessary information. When I printed this information received from the user to the console on the product editing page, the gravity value was written as length. I researched but couldn't find the reason. The emit structure I created was a bit long. Can you give me suggestions for writing a shorter and cleaner code?
I tried to send the data in a single emit but I got an error because the emit received only one data.
modal component:

  @Output() dimensionalWeightCalculated: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() width: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() length: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() gravity: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() height: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

...

 calculateDesi(): void {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.desiForm.valid) {
      const { length, width, height, gravity } = this.desiForm.value;
      const dimensionalWeight = gravity ? parseFloat(gravity) : (length * width * height) / 3000;
  
      this.dimensionalWeightCalculated.emit(dimensionalWeight); // Sadece tek bir değer yayınlayın
      this.length.emit(length);
      this.length.emit(gravity);
      console.log(gravity)
      this.width.emit(width);
      this.height.emit(height);
  
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
    }
  }

product edit component:
openDimensionalWeightCalculator(): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DimensionalWeightCalculatorComponent, { centered: true, size: 'lg' });

    modalRef.componentInstance.dimensionalWeightCalculated.subscribe((dimensionalWeight: number) => {
      console.log('Calculated dimensional weight:', dimensionalWeight);
      this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail')?.get('dimensional_weight')?.setValue(dimensionalWeight.toString());
      modalRef.close();
    });

    modalRef.componentInstance.length.subscribe((length: number) => {
      console.log('length:', length);
      this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail')?.get('length')?.setValue(length.toString());
      modalRef.close();
    });

    modalRef.componentInstance.gravity.subscribe((gravity: number) => {
      console.log('gravity:', gravity);
      this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail')?.get('weight')?.setValue(gravity.toString());
      modalRef.close();
    });

    modalRef.componentInstance.width.subscribe((width: number) => {
      console.log('width:', width);
      this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail')?.get('width')?.setValue(width.toString());
      modalRef.close();
    });

    modalRef.componentInstance.height.subscribe((height: number) => {
      console.log('height:', height);
      this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail')?.get('height')?.setValue(height.toString());
      modalRef.close();
    });
  }
}


current console output:

Calculated dimensional weight: 4
length: 1
length: 4
4
width: 2
height: 3


We can use combineLatest from rxjs to get all the values simultaneously.
openDimensionalWeightCalculator(): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DimensionalWeightCalculatorComponent, { centered: true, size: 'lg' });
    combineLatest(
       modalRef.componentInstance.dimensionalWeightCalculated,
       modalRef.componentInstance.length,
       modalRef.componentInstance.gravity,
       modalRef.componentInstance.width,
       modalRef.componentInstance.height,
    ).subscribe(([
       dimensional_weight,
       length, 
       gravity, 
       width, 
       height
      ]: Array<any>) => {
          const ProductDetailCtrl = this.productEditForm.get('ProductDetail');
          if(ProductDetailCtrl) {
               const patchValueObj = {
                   dimensional_weight,
                   length, 
                   gravity, 
                   width, 
                   height 
               };
               // remove all undefined and falsy values except zero
               const result = {};
               const patchValueObjFiltered = Object.keys(object).forEach(k => (object[k] || object[k] === 0) && (result[k] = object[k]));
               
               ProductDetailCtrl.patchValue(result);
          }
          modalRef.close();
    });
}

